# Microsoft Word with Automatic numbering that replace written number in text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I write a document in word and put number of each paragraph. for example like this:

```
1- abasdasdasdasdasddfgasdfglkf
2- asdfasdfasjdlfjalskdfjklasdf
3- sdfsadflasdk;kfg;dkfg;dfgkdfg
```

> is there anyway that can convert these lines to automatic numbering
>   without add another number?  (when I convert to automatic numbering I
>   see: 1- 1- abasdasdasdasdasddfgasdfglkf,  2- 2- ....)

Comment: Enable autonumbering. If so, when You press Enter key at the end of the first line it will be autoconverted to the numbered list... then delete the CR inserted by pressing Del key. Repeat it on each line (You may record the macro for this operation).

Comment: Remove the numbers before.

Comment: @Toto there is 1000 lines, how I remove all?

Comment: @Akina would you please show me how I can write a macro?

Comment: Posess the cursor to the first line. Start macro recorder. Press End, Enter, Del. Stop macro recorder. Save the macro recorded into "This document", assigning some unusable key combination to it. Then simply press this key combination as much as You need (check the cursor is posessed on the string You want to convert to the num list). If You are not novice in VBA You can edit this macro (add cycle, for example). Remember - this macro works correctly only on single-line paragraphs. To convert multi-line paragraph You need to posess the cursor to the last line of it manually (or by VBA code).

Comment: Using Regex in find and replace. Find `^\d+-` Replace with nothing.

Comment: @Toto your regex is wrong !

Comment: @Akina is it possible to post your solution via easy step as an answer?

Comment: How is it wrong? It matches 1 or more digit followed by a dash at the beginning of a line. This is exactly what you want. Or your example is wrong.

Comment: @Toto In Microsoft Word's Search and Replace?

Comment: @Akina: Not sure for words (I don't have it) but this a very basic regex that works with many regex flavour. It works fine with LibreOffice Writer

Comment: @Toto MS Word has its own "regular expressions syntax" not compatible with the common one, while Libre uses standard regex library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Position the cursor to the first line.
- Start macro recorder.
- Press End, Enter, Del.
- Stop macro recorder.
- Save the macro recorded into "This document", assigning some unused key combination to it.
- Then simply press this key combination as much as you need (check that the cursor is positioned on the string you want to convert to the numbered list).

If you are not a novice in VBA, you can edit this macro (add cycle, for example).

Remember - this macro works correctly only on single-line paragraphs. To convert a multi-line paragraph, you need to position the cursor to the last line of it manually (or by VBA code).